# Assign value from Counter to a list

Tags: python, list, counter

Suppose I have the following lists:

```
l1 = ['Hello', 'world', 'world']
l2 = ['Hello', 'world', 'world', 'apple']
```

for `l1` I count the distinct element as:

```
Counter(l1)
```

that gives:

```
Counter({'Hello': 1, 'world': 2})
```

now I would want to go through `l2` and assign the values above to it such that I get:

```
[1,2,2,0]
```

as you can see for `apple` we assigned 0 as there is no value for it in the counter. I wonder how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like so.

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = ['Hello', 'world', 'world']
l2 = ['Hello', 'world', 'world', 'apple']

c1 = Counter(l1)

res = [c1[i] for i in l2]
print(res)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 2, 0]
```

Old Solution (before the comment by user2357112 supports Monica)

```
res = [c1.get(i, 0) for i in l2]
```

Comment: No point using `get` - `Counter` indexing already works like that anyway.

Comment: I did not know this, thanks, will edit that part